# Cannot use object of type mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get the result from my database table basis_pengetahuan & penyakit but it throws error. I don't know why it throws error

The following line

```
if (isset($_POST['input'])) {
    $pilihgejala = $_POST['gejala'];
    $terpilih = count($pilihgejala);
    for($x=0;$x<$terpilih;$x++){
        $queryselect = "select distinct p.kode_penyakit, p.nama_penyakit from basis_pengetahuan b, penyakit p where b.gejala_penyakit ='$gejala[$x]' and p.nama_penyakit = b.nama_penyakit group by nama_penyakit";
        $insertquery = mysqli_query($con, $queryselect);
        $hasilfinal = mysqli_fetch_array($insertquery);
    }
    echo "<tr>    
    <td>".$x."</td>
    <td>".$hasilfinal['kode_penyakit']."</td>
    <td>".$hasilfinal['nama_penyakit']."</td>
    <td><a href='hasil.php?id=".$hasilfinal['kode_penyakit']."'><i class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in `C:\xampp\htdocs\sispak\diagnosa.php:179` Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in `C:\xampp\htdocs\sispak\diagnosa.php` on line 179

line 179 is

```
$queryselect = "select distinct p.kode_penyakit, p.nama_penyakit from basis_pengetahuan b, penyakit p where b.gejala_penyakit ='$gejala[$x]' and p.nama_penyakit = b.nama_penyakit group by nama_penyakit";
```

Comment: Line 179 is where in your code? You expect us to guess?

Comment: The loop `for($x=0;$x<$terpilih;$x++){` will overwrite the variables on each iteration - querying the db needlessly for `n-1` iterations ~ rethink that logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$gejala` is the result from a `mysqli_query()` call and not an array returned by `mysqli_fetch_array()`. You must use a `mysqli_fetch_*()` function to return the value of a result set.